# How to change service user in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, users, services, non-root-user

I created a service by adding a custom **.service* file in `/etc/systemd/system` and then running `systemctl daemon-reload`. However, I can start or stop the service only under `root`. I would actually like the service to always run as a different user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the service to run as a specific user, put this in the [Service] session of the **.service* file:

```
[Service]
User=username
```

Where ***'username'*** is the name of the user that you want the service to run as.

If you want to start/stop the service as another user, just edit your sudo file (use visudo), and put something like this there:

```
%devel ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop your.stuff.service,       \
                              /bin/systemctl start your.stuff.service
```

Where:

***devel*** - Is the name of the group that you want to be able to sudo

***your.stuff*** - Is the name of the service you want to run.

I hope this answer helps you.